# Corrective shapekey bone rotation

Tags: armature, drivers, shape-keys

When i set up my shapekey to react to a bone rotation , it will only react to a positive value.

How can i make it react to a bone negative rotation instead? I only get " x rotation " in my driver's "TYPE" option. I do not have a " -X rotation " or anything like that , so my bone won't trigger my shapekey as i wish.

Comment: You can use a scripted expression driver, which gives you access to reasonable amounts of Python math.  For what you're asking about, you might consider an expression like abs(var), which will give you the absolute value of your rotation.

Answer (score 0):

There may be another way but you can create a *Modifier > Generator* for this driver and give a *x^1* value of -1:

[image]